# Cannot install ipython on rhel 5.8 using pip

Tags: python, pip, ipython, python-2.4, rhel5

I am trying to install ipython on my rhel 5.8 server but it gives the below error.

```
└──> sudo pip install ipython
[sudo] password for ronak: 
Downloading/unpacking ipython
  Downloading ipython-0.13.tar.gz (6.1Mb): 6.1Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in ?
      File "/usr/local/home/ronak/build/ipython/setup.py", line 23
        from __future__ import print_function
    SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in ?

  File "/usr/local/home/ronak/build/ipython/setup.py", line 23

    from __future__ import print_function

SyntaxError: future feature print_function is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/ronak/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPython ≥ 0.11 requires Python ≥ 2.6.  That error suggests you have Python 2.5.

If you must use Python 2.5, you can do:

```
pip install ipython==0.10.2
```

Which is the last version that supported Python 2.5.

Comment: I think 0.10.2 *should* work on 2.4, but since the last real release of Python 2.4 was in 2006, it is fairly untested, and not officially supported.